# Git marks files as changed, can not check out or revert

Tags: windows, git

Git is totally freaking me out right now. I am completely unable to remove these modificiations:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   Exchange Plugins/VWSDK/SDKVW(234280)/Source/Samples/Stage 2/old resource/AOE_EN.r
        modified:   Exchange Plugins/VWSDK/SDKVW(234280)/Source/Samples/Stage 2/old resource/AOE_NL.r
        modified:   Exchange Plugins/VWSDK/SDKVW(234280)/Source/Samples/Stage 2/old resource/Afvoerleiding_NL.r
        modified:   Exchange Plugins/VWSDK/SDKVW(234280)/Source/Samples/Stage 2/old resource/EditLicense_NL.r
        modified:   Exchange Plugins/VWSDK/SDKVW(234280)/Source/Samples/Stage 2/old resource/Guideline_NL.r
        modified:   Exchange Plugins/VWSDK/SDKVW(234280)/Source/Samples/Stage 2/old resource/Leiding3D_NL.r
        modified:   Exchange Plugins/VWSDK/SDKVW(234280)/Source/Samples/Stage 2/old resource/RV_NL.r
        modified:   Exchange Plugins/VWSDK/SDKVW(234280)/Source/Samples/Stage 2/old resource/Radiator_NL.r
        modified:   Exchange Plugins/VWSDK/SDKVW(234280)/Source/Samples/Stage 2/old resource/ReplaceSymbol_EN.r
        modified:   Exchange Plugins/VWSDK/SDKVW(234280)/Source/Samples/Stage 2/old resource/ReplaceSymbol_NL.r

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

But I never changed these files, and nothing else has. They are from some SDK and really shouldn't be touched anyway. Using `git diff -R` shows that it seems to be some line endings issue:

```
λ git diff -R
diff --git b/Exchange Plugins/VWSDK/SDKVW(234280)/Source/Samples/Stage 2/old resource/AOE_EN.r a/Exchange Plugins/VWSDK/SDKVW(234280)/Source/Samples/Stage 2/old resource/AOE_EN.r
index ef6bf97..e7cb032 100755
--- b/Exchange Plugins/VWSDK/SDKVW(234280)/Source/Samples/Stage 2/old resource/AOE_EN.r
+++ a/Exchange Plugins/VWSDK/SDKVW(234280)/Source/Samples/Stage 2/old resource/AOE_EN.r
@@ -1,27 +1,27 @@
-#ifndef REZ_FOR_MACHO
-       #define REZ_FOR_MACHO 0
-#endif
-
-#if REZ_FOR_MACHO
-       #include <Carbon/Carbon.r>
-#else
-       #include "MacTypes.r"
-#endif
-
-#include "GSRsrc.r"
-
-// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-// The parametric object resources
-resource 'STR#' (18200, "CExtObj")  {
-       {
-        /* 1 */                "Organisation - Objects",
-        /* 2 */                "Organisation - Objects",
-        /* 3 */                "HVACS",
-        /* 4 */                "Extension Tool : Do something",
-       }
-};
-
-resource 'TEXT' (18200, "CExtObjAdvComplex:help") {
-       "some help\n\n"
-       "Create a radiator."
-};
+#ifndef REZ_FOR_MACHO^M
+       #define REZ_FOR_MACHO 0^M
+#endif^M
+^M
+#if REZ_FOR_MACHO^M
+       #include <Carbon/Carbon.r>^M
+#else^M
+       #include "MacTypes.r"^M
+#endif^M
+^M
+#include "GSRsrc.r"^M
+^M
+// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^M
+// The parametric object resources^M
+resource 'STR#' (18200, "CExtObj")  {^M
+       {^M
```

What I've tried:

- `git reset --hard`
- `git checkout .`
- `git stash` (resulting in the files being stashed, but the "changes" still exist locally)
- `core.autocrlf` on `input`, `false` and `true`, both globally and locally and all the commands from above once again

The only thing that "worked" was committing these apparent "modifications". But I did this from another branch, and now I am unable to merge into master because these "changes" still exist there and it tells me to commit or stash the changed before merging.

Using `git version 2.7.4.windows.1`

Comment: git stash should do what you want. What happens when you do `git stash` and `git status`?

Comment: Have you tried `git reset --soft HEAD~1` ?

Comment: @MartinGottweis When I do `git stash` I have the "changes" in the stash, as well as in the current working directory. So `git status` shows the same after `git stash`

Comment: @Baruch After `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, the same files are still modified and the ones changed in the previous commit (aka `HEAD~1`) are staged (as expected).

Comment: @MartinGottweis In case it helps, here's a video: https://vid.me/9rom  --Do not wonder, the `HEAD` is detached because in order to be able to continue working, I just added the "changed" and commited them, Git is satisfied then (as I described in the question). But I created a tag at the version where it wasn't satisifed. I would have preferred not to commit these "apparent changes".

Comment: There are two common problems that crop up on Windows (vs Linux): file name case insensitivity, and LF vs CR-LF line endings.  This looks like the latter.  Both `core.autocrlf` and `.gitattributes` can affect the CR-LF thing, but since I don't use Windows I am not sure of the details.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is you have detached head.

Try running `git checkout -b newbranch` and then `git stash`

Also is there a chance you have cinema 4D running and this is preventing git from removing the files?

Comment: It's not a problem with the HEAD being detached. I've continue by committing these "changes", otherwise I wouldn't have been able to continue working. To record the video, I went back to the commit before, thus the detached HEAD state.

Comment: I like the videos ;-). Could you try to rename one of the files manually?